# How can I optimize searching and matching through multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to match up the elements in 2 different arrays. Array_A is a 3d map of A_Clouds, Array_B is a 3d map of B_Clouds. Each "cloud" is continuous, i.e. any isolated pixels would define a new cloud. The values of the pixels are a single, unique integer for each cloud. Non-cloud values are 0. Here's a 2D example:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

The output I need is simply the IDs (for both clouds) of each A_Cloud which is overlapping with a B_Cloud, and the number (locations not needed) of pixels which are overlapping between those clouds.

The problem is that these are both very large 3 dimensional arrays (~2000x2000x200, both are the same size). I'm basically doing a bunch of nested for loops, which is of course very slow. Is there a faster way that I could approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

This is what I have right now (simplified to 2d):

```
final_matches = []
for Acloud_id in ACloud_list:
    Acloud_locs = list(set([(i,j) for j, line in enumerate(Array_A) for i,pix in enumerate(line) if pix == Acloud_id]))

    matches = []
    for loc in Acloud_locs:
        Bcloud_pix = Array_B[loc[0]][loc[1]]
        if Bcloud_pix:
            matches.append(Bcloud_pix)

counter=collections.Counter(matches)
final_matches.append([Acloud_id, counter])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the arrays sparse? (i.e. high % of values will be zero) And are there a large number of clouds?

Comment: The arrays are quite sparse (~80% zeros). There are a total of ~500 clouds in the 3d cubes, with a maximum of ~100 in a single 2d slice. Each cloud is ~20 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some considerations here:

```
for Acloud_id in ACloud_list:
    Acloud_locs = list(set([(i,j) for j, line in enumerate(Array_A) for i,pix in enumerate(line) if pix == Acloud_id]))
```

If I've read that right, this needs to check every pixel in the array in order to generate the set, and it repeats that for every cloud in A. So if you have 500 clouds, you're checking every pixel 500 times. This is not going to scale well!

Might be more efficient to store the overlap counts in a dict, and just go through the arrays once:

```
overlaps=dict()
for i in possible_x_coords: # define these however you like
    for j in possible_y_coords:
        if (Array_A[i][j] and Array_B[i][j]):
            overlaps[(Array_A[i][j],Array_B[i][j])] = 1 + overlaps.get((Array_A[i][j],Array_B[i][j]),0)
```

(apologies for any errors, I'm on the road and can't test my code)

update: You've clarified that the arrays are about 80% sparse. If that figure was a lot higher, and if you had control over the format of your inputs, I'd suggest looking into sparse array formats - if your input only stores the non-zero values for A, this can save you the trouble of checking for zero values in A. However, for something that's only 80% sparse, I'm not sure how much efficiency this would add.

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Only change is that instead of overlaps.get(..., default=0) I need to use overlaps.get(..., 0).